# Adding domain name to html page in Play framework 2 using java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework-2.0, multi-tenant

I am building multi-tenant site using Play framework 2.1.x in Java.

There are few pages which vary few fields,
So while calling the page from controller I am thinking of adding domain name infront of Result like `return ok(domain_htmlpage.render());`

I have the `domain_htmlpage` in my folder.
But I cannot render domain name dynamically.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use Java reflections for rendering templates in your action per domain
2. or use i.e. `switch` statement in your action to render required view per domain
3. or use **one** view and use `@if` statement in it to display (or hide) blocks available only for specific domain
4. Finaly if list of domains is unknown at the moment, name the views by some prefix and in your `application.conf` create of map prefix vs domain.

The last is most flexible as you can use one view per many specified domains (and subdomains) if required